# Returning multiple values on the basis of size of list

Tags: java

I am using TestNG Data Provider and constituting following data set depending on the elements in the list. Offer list would have either one or at-most 2 elements and I would like to test with all of the available elements, along with one extra data value which I always test with -

```
private Object[][] getProductOffers() {
    List<ExtendedProductOffer> offerList = getOfferList();
    if(offerList.size()>1) {
        return new Object[][]
            {
                {
                    offerList.get(0)
                },
                {
                    offerList.get(1)
                }, 
                {
                    anotherDataElement;
                },

            };
    } else {
        return new Object[][]
            {
                {
                    offerList.get(0)
                },
                {
                    anotherDataElement;
                },                    
            };
    }

}
```

This code looks clunky to me. How can I improve it?

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving **real, existing, working code.** Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: but this is real, existing, working code and not hypothetical example.

Comment: So where does `getOfferList` and `anotherDataElement` come from ? Reading `anotherDataelement` just looks like example code for me. `getOfferList` reads like a method but it doesn't seem to be one. At least show how and where these variables are declared.

Comment: I hid the implementation of getOfferList() for brevity of question. Why is implementation of getOfferList and dataElement important?

Comment: You didn't paste the content of your IDE here, which IMO became a problem now, because you made typing errors. You mentioned in your last comment `getOfferList()` which now seems to be a method. With more context like what `anotherDataElement`'s type is one could mention in the review that its name isn't the best.

Comment: well I did not paste IDE content as it may contain sensitive info and had to come up with fictious names.

Comment: For future reference. codereview is the exception where it's preferable to have a big post (at most 65k characters I think) that contains **all** the **relevant** code so we can give proper advice. As you can tell from the comments we're missing a lot of information now (what type your `anotherDataElement` is being the biggest problem).

Comment: noted fore future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it does look clunky.
What you want to do is converting a list into an array and adding an "endelement".
Well just write it that way, without spreading it to thin on the screen:

```
  //Lets assume this is the list
  List<String> listToBeConverted = new ArrayList<String>();
  String stringToAdd = "TheThingYouWantOnTheEndOfTheArray";

  //Inside your Method do this:

  String[] array = listToBeConverted.toArray(new String[listToBeConverted.size() + 1]);

  array[array.length - 1] = stringToAdd;
  return array;
```